# How can I remove dependency of secrets from application pod in K3s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-secrets, k3s, kubernetes-security

I am having a k3s cluster with my application pods running. In all the pods when I login ( with `kubectl exec <pod_name> -n <ns> -it /bin/bash` command ) there is **`kubernetes.io`** directory which contain secret token that anyone can get if they do  `cat token` :

```
root@Ubuntu-VM: kubectl exec app-test-pod -n app-system -it /bin/bash
root@app-test-pod:/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount# ls -lhrt
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Oct 11 12:07 token -> ..data/token
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Oct 11 12:07 namespace -> ..data/namespace
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Oct 11 12:07 ca.crt -> ..data/ca.crt
```

This seems a security threat (or vulnerability). Can someone let me know if there is a way to remove this dependency from pod so that I can restrict users (even root users also) to access this secret if they login to pod ? Also If this is possible then how will pods do communicate with the API Server ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the purpose of a pod's service account, if \`automountServiceAccountToken\` is set to false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69343508/whats-the-purpose-of-a-pods-service-account-if-automountserviceaccounttoken)

Comment: @ChinHuang: Actually No. I know what is Service Account. I am looking for the way by which I can restrict users to access the secret token inside Kubernetes.io

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To clarify a couple of things:

> This seems a security threat (or vulnerability).

It actually isn't a vulnerability unless you configured it to be one.
The ServiceAccount you are talking about is the `deafult` one which exists in every namespace.
By default that ServiceAccount does not have any permissions that make it unsafe.
If you want to you *can* add certain rights to the `default` ServiceAccount [using RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/). For example you can configure it to be able to list all Pods in the same namespace but unless you do that, the ServiceAccount is not considered a vulnerability at all and will not be able to retrieve any useful information.
This applies to *all* ServiceAccounts, not only the `default` one.

> Can someone let me know if there is a way to remove this dependency from pod so that I can restrict users (even root users also) to access this secret if they login to pod ?

Yes it is possible, actually there are two options:

Firstly there is a field called `automountServiceAccountToken` for the `spec` section in Pods which you can set to `false` if you do not want the `default` ServiceAccount to be mounted at all.

Here is an example:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  automountServiceAccountToken: false
  [...]
```

Other than that you can create/edit a ServiceAccount and assign it the `automountServiceAccountToken: false` field:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
automountServiceAccountToken: false
metadata:
  namespace: default
[...]
```

> Also If this is possible then how will pods do communicate with the API Server ?

Pods actually do not need to communicate with the API server at all.
Even when using features like a `livenessProbe` it is not necessary for Pods to communicate with the API server at all.
As a matter of fact most Pods *never* communicate with the API server.
The only reason a Pod would need to communicate with the API server is if it is planning on directly interacting with the cluster. Usually this is never required unless you want to write a [custom operator](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/) or something similar.
You will still be able to use all the functionality a Pod has to offer you even if you do not mount the ServiceAccount because all those features are based around a Kubernetes communicating with your Pod not the other way around (a `livenessProbe` for example is being evaluated by `kubelet`, there is no need at all for the Pod to communicate with the API).